# How to define new cite command with specific citation format?

Tags: citing

The standard `\cite{some_ref}`  command produce citation text like `[1]`, but i'm looking for citation like `[1*]`.
How can i define new cite command for such behavior?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! There are many possible citation/bibliography formats -- please provide some background to your question. Should a star be added to every label number? Should a star inidicate some kind of "special" source?

Comment: Sorry for confusing question. I need indicate special source. So i think it's better to define new command like \cites{some_ref} in this case, instead of redefining existing command. I'll update question to remove confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `natbib`, there's no need to define any new commands; you can achieve the desired effect using the `\citetext` and `\citealp` commands:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={Steve Somebody},
title= {The Title},
year={2011},
publisher={The publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citetext{\citealp{test}*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, defined new command as in your example `\def\mycite#1{\citetext{\citealp{#1}*}}`

Comment: Can I do it without using the `natbib`?

Answer (score 2):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={Steve Somebody},
titel= {The Title},
year={2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\mycite{%
  \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@mycitex}{\@tempswafalse\@mycitex[]}}
\def\@mycitex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@mycite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}} 
\def\@mycite#1#2{[{#1*\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{test}\qquad \mycite{test} \qquad \mycite[p.~1]{test}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: then all `\cite` get the star

Comment: @Herbert: I edited my post ;-)

Comment: Why don't you just redefine `\@cite` to `\@mycite` rather than copying over the entire contents of `\@citex`?  I can't even tell what you changed other than the star in `\@mycite`.

Comment: @Ryan: if I redefine `\@cite` , every cite-command get the star.

Comment: @Marco: Your sample works as i expected. But when i tried it with my real document, i got error
`! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.
\mycite  ->\@i
              fnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@mycitex}{\@tempswafalse\@mycitex[]}`

Seems, problem with natbib package.
How your sample can be fixed in this case?

Comment: @TheBug: you have to use `\makeatletter`--`\makeatother`. See also the example of Herbert.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks, it works with `\makeatletter--\makeatother`

Comment: @Marco: You could do something like `\def\mycite{{\let\@cite=\@mycite\cite}}`.  Unless `\cite` doesn't `\global`ize the things it changes externally, this won't break anything.

Answer (score 2):

with a second switch it is a bit shorter. Use `\cite` or `cite*`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={Steve Somebody},
titel= {The Title},
year={2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@tempswb
\DeclareRobustCommand\cite{%
  \@ifnextchar*{\@tempswbtrue\cite@i}{\@tempswbfalse\cite@i*}}
\def\cite@i*{\@ifnextchar[{\@tempswatrue\@citex}{\@tempswafalse\@citex[]}}
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswb*\fi\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\cite{test}\qquad \cite*{test} \qquad \cite*[p.~1]{test}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your sample works fine. But with my document it leads to error
`Runaway argument?
]{test1} \cite *{test2} 
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par`
Can you help with this issue?

Comment: @TheBug: `natbib` redefines all macros itself and it would have been a good idea if you had this mentioned before ...